# How to add items in buffer array which dynamically grows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have source table which contains few records.

When I click each record from source table, it calls `AddSelectedItem(sValue)` function which adds those particular records in destination table.

What I would like to achieve is that, when we add each record from source to destination, the array should append every time.

To achieve this I have written a function `addItemToList(target, item) {` which seems not adding records in array.

Source table

```
<div id="panel_content" style="width:100%;text-align:left;height:190px;overflow-y:hidden;">
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="165">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
               <div id="panel_result" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; height: 150px; overflow: hidden auto; display: inline;">
                  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top;">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="titleStyle" style="width:165px;white-space:nowrap;">Name</td>
                           <td class="titleStyle" style="width:165px;white-space:nowrap;">Code</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top;">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td width="165px" nowrap=""><a ondrag="return false;" href="javascript:AddSelectedItem( "ABC^0090^C71F952E-ED74-4138-8061-4B50B9EF6463^0090)">ABC</a></td>
                           <td width="165px" nowrap=""><a ondrag="return false;" href="javascript:AddSelectedItem( "ABC^0090^C71F952E-ED74-4138-8061-4B50B9EF6463^0090)">0090</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td width="165px" nowrap=""><a ondrag="return false;" href="javascript:AddSelectedItem( "ABC^CRE^C5F3A034-9F28-4767-86EC-9E9F1394ED9C^CRE")" >ABC</a></td>
                           <td width="165px" nowrap=""><a ondrag="return false;" href="javascript:AddSelectedItem( "ABC^CRE^C5F3A034-9F28-4767-86EC-9E9F1394ED9C^CRE")" >CRE</a></td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Destination table

```
<div id="panel_content2" style="width:100%;text-align:left;height:190px;overflow-y:hidden;">
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="165">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
               <div id="panel_header2" style="height:30px;width:100%;text-align:center;display: inline;">
                  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="Center" border="0" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:collapse;valign:top;">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="titleStyle" style="width:250px;white-space:nowrap;">Name</td>
                           <td class="titleStyle" style="width:250px;white-space:nowrap;">Code</td>
                           <td class="titleStyle" style="width:5px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
               <div id="panel_result2" style="height:150px;width:99%;overflow:auto;text-align:center;position:30;vertical-align:top;height:150;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;">
                  <table id="TSelected" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;border-width: 0px; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-collapse: collapse; valign: top;">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr id="TR1" valign="top">
                           <td width="2px">
                              <input type="HIDDEN" id="list_name_1" name="list_name_1" value="ABC">
                              <input type="HIDDEN" id="list_code_1" name="list_code_1" value="C71F952E-ED74-4138-8061-4B50B9EF6463">
                              <input type="HIDDEN" id="list_comparecode_1" name="list_comparecode_1" value="0090">
                           <td width="244">ABC</td>
                           <td width="256">0090</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var strArr = "";
function AddSelectedItem(sValue) {
    var AddRow = true;
    sValue = Replace(sValue, "~", "%");
    strArr = sValue.split("^");
    var TR, TD;
    var theTable = document.getElementById("TSelected");
    var Tablerow = theTable.rows.length;

    // Check the row exists
    for (d = Tablerow - 1; d > -1; d--) {
        TRId = theTable.rows[d].id;
        idNum = TRId.replace("TR", "");
        codeObj = document.getElementById("list_comparecode_" + idNum);
        if (codeObj.value == strArr[3]) {
            AddRow = false;
        }
    }

    if (AddRow) {
        //Get unique row number     
        RowNum = 0;
        for (d = Tablerow - 1; d > -1; d--) {
            TRId = theTable.rows[d].id;
            idNum = TRId.replace("TR", "");
            if (parseInt(idNum) > RowNum) {
                RowNum = parseInt(idNum);
            }
        }
        RowNum = RowNum + 1;

        var insertIndex = 0;
        TR = document.getElementById("TSelected").insertRow(insertIndex);
            TR.id = "TR" + RowNum;
            TR.vAlign = 'top';

            TD = TR.insertCell(insertIndex);
            TD.width = "2px";
            TD.innerHTML = "<INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' ID='list_name_" + RowNum + "' NAME='list_name_" + RowNum + "' value='" + strArr[0] + "'><INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' ID='list_code_" + RowNum + "' NAME='list_code_" + RowNum + "' value='" + strArr[2] + "'><INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' ID='list_comparecode_" + RowNum + "' NAME='list_comparecode_" + RowNum + "' value='" + strArr[3] + "'>";

            TD = TR.insertCell(insertIndex + 1);
            TD.width = "244";
            TD.innerHTML = strArr[0]; //name

            TD = TR.insertCell(insertIndex + 2);
            TD.width = "256";
            TD.innerHTML = strArr[1]; //code

            TD = TR.insertCell(insertIndex + 3);
            TD.width = "5px";
            document.getElementById("RowCount").value = RowNum;
        
           const target = strArr.target;
           addItemToList(destination, target);
    }
    ChangeSaveCloseButtonStatus();
}


const destinationList = [];
const destination = document.getElementById('#panel_result2');
function addItemToList(target, item) {  
    const index = [...item.parentNode.children].indexOf(item);
    const newItem = item.cloneNode(true);
    newItem.dataset.sourceIndex = index;
    target.append(newItem);
    destinationList.push(newItem.textContent);
    console.log('buffer array:', destinationList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most immediate problem you're running into is that you're trying to call the `replace` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) as a function. Line 4 of your script should just be:

```
sValue.replace("~", "%");
```

Beyond that, you are also calling `document.getElementById("RowCount")`, when there is no element with an id of `RowCount` in your HTML.

There are much easier ways of copying elements without needing to go through so much work:

```
    <table id="source">
      <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>123</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="destination">
    </table>

    <script>
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#source tr");
      const destination = document.querySelector("#destination");
      rows.forEach(row => {
        row.addEventListener('click', () => {
          destination.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true));
        });
      })
    </script>
```

Note that if you *need* each row to have an `id`, you should change its clone's to a unique value. If you *need* to maintain a list of unique values for another purpose, use a Set (or maintain an array if you prefer):

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#source tr");
const destination = document.querySelector("#destination");
let list = new Set();
rows.forEach(row => {
  row.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!list.has(row)) {
      destination.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true));
      list.add(row);
    }
  });
});
```